# Sass border top, left, bottom, right

Tags: sass, compass-sass

I thought I could break border up into its individual parts like this...

```
border {
    top:1px solid cyan;
    right:1px solid yellow;
    bottom:1px solid magenta;
    left:1px solid black;
}
```

Now I can't find it in the docs. The syntax doesn't even look right.

Was this ever possible and if not, is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a colon after border.

```
div {
    border: {
        top: 1px solid cyan;
        right: 1px solid yellow;
        bottom: 1px solid magenta;
        left: 1px solid black;
    }
}
```

[Preview](http://cssdeck.com/labs/sc3pnbmt)